# Is there a way to block Pandora's Paralysis Attack

Tags: smt-persona

i'm on the final battle for Shin Megami Tensei: Persona, i'm on level 46 and i don't really think i'll have too much trouble against Pandora (Marso dies easily but she's always been crap)

the problem i'm having is that Pandora's Cocoon Form has an attack which attacks the entire party and can cause Paralysis, well, a number of times i only got a game over because of it

is there a way i can block the attack or block the Paralysis it causes, it doesn't have to be the entire party, just one character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To defend against paralysis, you should get a Persona that's "Not affected by spirit"

The information was retrieved from this link:

> http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/924580-shin-megami-tensei-persona/65662188

There are also other helpful hints regarding the final boss.